# Read file .txt to array and split

Tags: c, arrays, string, file, split

i'm here to ask for some help. I want to read a .txt with this format:

```
20
20

1 2
1 2
3 4 2 2
5 4 1 1 1 1
4 2 1 3 1
3 2 1 7
4 1 3 3 2
2 10 1
5 8 2 1 1 1
3 8 1 1
4 9 1 1 1
4 3 8 1 1
2 2 12
4 3 2 4 3
4 2 2 4 3
3 3 4 2
2 3 2
3 2 1 2
2 5 4
2 4 2

1 6
1 9
2 9 3
4 4 4 1 1
3 1 2 8
3 4 9 1
4 2 7 1 1
2 7 1
3 1 5 1
3 8 5 1
4 1 3 7 1
5 1 2 2 3 1
5 2 1 2 2 1
3 2 4 1
4 2 1 4 1
6 1 1 1 1 2 1
4 1 2 1 2
3 8 1 2
1 4
1 2
```

I have some piece of code written. It copies each line of the .txt (I don't want to read the 20's) and print it directly in the cmd when we run it. Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>



int main( int argc, char *argv[]){

    FILE*fp;
    int i=0, dimension[2];
    char row[128];
    int n_rows, n_columns;
    char *v_row, *v_col;


    fp=fopen(argv[1],"r");


    if(fp == NULL){
        printf("File not found\n");
        exit(0);
                }
    while(i<3){

        fgets(row, 128, fp);
        sscanf(row, "%d", &dimension[i]);
        i++;
        }
    n_rows=dimension[0];
    n_columns=dimension[1];

    printf("dimension: %d x %d\n\n", n_rows, n_columns);
    v_row=malloc((n_rows+1)*sizeof(char));
    v_col=malloc((n_columns+1)*sizeof(char));

    for(i=0; i<n_rows; i++){
        fgets(row, 128, fp);
        printf("row: %s\n", row);


        }
    for(i=0;i<n_columns; i++){
        fgets(row, 128, fp);
        printf("row: %s\n", row);
        sscanf(row,"%s", &v_col[i]);
    }


    fclose(fp);

    exit(-1);
}
```

But this is not my final goal. What I really want to do is to put each line in an array, splitting the first number to one array and the rest of the line to another array, but unfortunately I can't figure a way to do it.

Comment: Putting a single value in an array?

Comment: If you will `mmap` your file, checking and reading will be simpler: you will work with it just like with large string, OS will do all background work. To split data into portions you can use such functions as `strtok` and `strchr`. And I recommend you not to use `scanf` for getting integer values, but use `strtol` which is more flexible and allows to control data.

Comment: `while(i<3){ ... sscanf( row, "%d", &dimension[i]); }` There are only two elements in the dimension array; their indexes are `0` and `1`.

Answer (score 2):

You actually got the answer yourself. Use sscanf() to do your job

Example::

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char *tmp = "123 456 789 123 4652 128793";
    char arr[5], arr2[30];
    printf("tmp::\t%s\n",tmp);
    sscanf(tmp,"%s %[^\n]s",arr,arr2);
    printf("arr::\t%s\n",arr);
    printf("arr2::\t%s\n",arr2);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
tmp::   123 456 789 123 4652 128793
arr::   123
arr2::  456 789 123 4652 128793
```

EDIT::

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define LENGTH 42 // max length of line

int main()
{
    FILE *fp; // for the file
    int Nrow, Ncol;
    int loop;
    char line[LENGTH];
    char **arrRows_1stDim, **arrRows_2ndDim;
    char **arrCols_1stDim, **arrCols_2ndDim;
    char arr[20], arr2[20];
    fp = fopen("testDATA.txt","r"); // I saved your file with this name
    if(fp == NULL)
    {
        perror("testDATA.txt");
        return -1;
    }
    fscanf(fp,"%d", &Nrow);
    fscanf(fp,"%d", &Ncol);
    printf("Nrow::%d,\tNcol::%d\n",Nrow,Ncol);
    arrRows_1stDim = malloc(sizeof(char*) * Nrow);
    arrRows_2ndDim = malloc(sizeof(char*) * Nrow);
    arrCols_1stDim = malloc(sizeof(char*) * Ncol);
    arrCols_2ndDim = malloc(sizeof(char*) * Ncol);
    // check if our malloc() was allocated 
    if(arrRows_1stDim == NULL || arrRows_2ndDim == NULL || arrCols_1stDim == NULL || arrCols_2ndDim == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"Couldn't malloc()");
        return -1;
    }
    printf("Reading Rows...\n\n");
    for(loop=0;loop<Nrow;loop++)
    {
        fgets(line,LENGTH,fp);
        if(strlen(line)==1)
            loop--;
        else
        {
            sscanf(line,"%s %[^\n]s",arr,arr2);
            //printf("Arr::%s,\tArr2::%s\n",arr,arr2);
            arrRows_1stDim[loop] = malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(arr) + 1));
            arrRows_2ndDim[loop] = malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(arr2) + 1));
            // check if our malloc() was allocated
            if(arrRows_1stDim[loop] == NULL || arrRows_2ndDim[loop] == NULL)
            {
                fprintf(stderr,"Couldn't malloc()");
                return -1;
            }
            strcpy(arrRows_1stDim[loop],arr);
            strcpy(arrRows_2ndDim[loop],arr2);
            //printf("arrRows_1stDim[loop]::%s,\tarrRows_2ndDim[loop]::%s\n",arrRows_1stDim[loop],arrRows_2ndDim[loop]);
        }
    }
    printf("\nReading Cols...\n\n");
    for(loop=0;loop<Ncol;loop++)
    {
        fgets(line,LENGTH,fp);
        if(strlen(line)==1)
            loop--;
        else
        {
            sscanf(line,"%s %[^\n]s",arr,arr2);
            //printf("Arr::%s,\tArr2::%s\n",arr,arr2);
            arrCols_1stDim[loop] = malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(arr) + 1));
            arrCols_2ndDim[loop] = malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(arr2) + 1));
            // check if our malloc() was allocated
            if(arrCols_1stDim[loop] == NULL || arrCols_2ndDim[loop] == NULL)
            {
                fprintf(stderr,"Couldn't malloc()");
                return -1;
            }
            strcpy(arrCols_1stDim[loop],arr);
            strcpy(arrCols_2ndDim[loop],arr2);
        }
    }
    printf("Let's see whether we read correctly or not...\n");
    printf("Printing Rows...\n");
    for(loop=0;loop<Nrow;loop++)
    {
        printf("Rows_1stArray:: %s,\t Rows_2ndArray:: %s\n",arrRows_1stDim[loop],arrRows_2ndDim[loop]);
    }
    printf("\nPrinting Cols...\n");
    for(loop=0;loop<Ncol;loop++)
    {
        printf("Rows_1stArray:: %s,\t Rows_2ndArray:: %s\n",arrCols_1stDim[loop],arrCols_2ndDim[loop]);
    }
    printf("\nFree Allocated Memory...\n");
    // free inner level
    for(loop=0;loop<Nrow;loop++)
    {
        free(arrRows_1stDim[loop]);
        free(arrRows_2ndDim[loop]);
    }
    // free outer level
    free(arrRows_1stDim);
    free(arrRows_2ndDim);        
    for(loop=0;loop<Ncol;loop++)
    {
        free(arrCols_1stDim[loop]);
        free(arrCols_2ndDim[loop]);
    }
    free(arrCols_1stDim);
    free(arrCols_2ndDim);
    fclose(fp);
    printf("Done!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Output::

```
Nrow::20,       Ncol::20
Reading Rows...


Reading Cols...

Let's see whether we read correctly or not...
Printing Rows...
Rows_1stArray:: 1,       Rows_2ndArray:: 2
Rows_1stArray:: 1,       Rows_2ndArray:: 2
Rows_1stArray:: 3,       Rows_2ndArray:: 4 2 2
Rows_1stArray:: 5,       Rows_2ndArray:: 4 1 1 1 1
Rows_1stArray:: 4,       Rows_2ndArray:: 2 1 3 1
Rows_1stArray:: 3,       Rows_2ndArray:: 2 1 7
Rows_1stArray:: 4,       Rows_2ndArray:: 1 3 3 2
Rows_1stArray:: 2,       Rows_2ndArray:: 10 1
Rows_1stArray:: 5,       Rows_2ndArray:: 8 2 1 1 1
Rows_1stArray:: 3,       Rows_2ndArray:: 8 1 1
Rows_1stArray:: 4,       Rows_2ndArray:: 9 1 1 1
Rows_1stArray:: 4,       Rows_2ndArray:: 3 8 1 1
Rows_1stArray:: 2,       Rows_2ndArray:: 2 12
Rows_1stArray:: 4,       Rows_2ndArray:: 3 2 4 3
Rows_1stArray:: 4,       Rows_2ndArray:: 2 2 4 3
Rows_1stArray:: 3,       Rows_2ndArray:: 3 4 2
Rows_1stArray:: 2,       Rows_2ndArray:: 3 2
Rows_1stArray:: 3,       Rows_2ndArray:: 2 1 2
Rows_1stArray:: 2,       Rows_2ndArray:: 5 4
Rows_1stArray:: 2,       Rows_2ndArray:: 4 2

Printing Cols...
Rows_1stArray:: 1,       Rows_2ndArray:: 6
Rows_1stArray:: 1,       Rows_2ndArray:: 9
Rows_1stArray:: 2,       Rows_2ndArray:: 9 3
Rows_1stArray:: 4,       Rows_2ndArray:: 4 4 1 1
Rows_1stArray:: 3,       Rows_2ndArray:: 1 2 8
Rows_1stArray:: 3,       Rows_2ndArray:: 4 9 1
Rows_1stArray:: 4,       Rows_2ndArray:: 2 7 1 1
Rows_1stArray:: 2,       Rows_2ndArray:: 7 1
Rows_1stArray:: 3,       Rows_2ndArray:: 1 5 1
Rows_1stArray:: 3,       Rows_2ndArray:: 8 5 1
Rows_1stArray:: 4,       Rows_2ndArray:: 1 3 7 1
Rows_1stArray:: 5,       Rows_2ndArray:: 1 2 2 3 1
Rows_1stArray:: 5,       Rows_2ndArray:: 2 1 2 2 1
Rows_1stArray:: 3,       Rows_2ndArray:: 2 4 1
Rows_1stArray:: 4,       Rows_2ndArray:: 2 1 4 1
Rows_1stArray:: 6,       Rows_2ndArray:: 1 1 1 1 2 1
Rows_1stArray:: 4,       Rows_2ndArray:: 1 2 1 2
Rows_1stArray:: 3,       Rows_2ndArray:: 8 1 2
Rows_1stArray:: 1,       Rows_2ndArray:: 4
Rows_1stArray:: 1,       Rows_2ndArray:: 2

Free Allocated Memory...
Done!
```

Comment: Binayaka Chakraborty thanks, but with that can I save that two parts splited in two diferent arrays, to work them later?

Comment: Yes you can, provided that the two array are accessible in your program later. But, you do know that every loop you do will overwrite the arrays right? If you want an alternative solution, I would advise to go for a 2D array, like ARR[N][DATA], where N is number of lines for row or col, and DATA is obviously the data segment shown above :)